# Manipulations only with certain elements from lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two List1:

```
{{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {5, -0.5}, {7, -0.4}}
```

and List2:

```
{{2, -0.1}, {3, -2}, {5, -2.5}, {7, -3.4}}
```

The List1 and List2 have the same first elements in their sublists. Can is it possible to get next List3:

```
{{2, -0.5}, {3, 1.1}, {5, 2}, {7, 3}}
```

where the first elements in sublists the same first elements in the List1 and List2, but at the same time, second elements are difference between the seconds elements from the Lists.

Answer (score 5):

We define

```
lista = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {5, -0.5}, {7, -0.4}};
listb = {{2, -0.1}, {3, -2}, {5, -2.5}, {7, -3.4}};
```

then we pick the elements

```
xx = lista[[All, 1]]
yy = (lista - listb)[[All, 2]]
```

and finally

```
Thread@{xx, yy}
```

gives

> `{{2, -0.5}, {3, 1.1}, {5, 2.}, {7, 3.}}`

Answer (score 5):

Without auxiliary variables:

```
list1 = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {5, -0.5}, {7, -0.4}};

list2 = {{2, -0.1}, {3, -2}, {5, -2.5}, {7, -3.4}};

list1 - list2 . {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}
(* {{2., -0.5}, {3., 1.1}, {5., 2.}, {7., 3.}} *)
```

The `.{{0,0},{0,1}}` effectively performs a matrix multiplication on the second list to set the first entries to 0. We can then simply subtract the lists from each other

Comment: This can be done now with new function `Threaded` as follow `list1 - list2 Threaded@{0, 1}`

Answer (score 4):

Another method which allows you to define more complicated operations on your list should you need it in later on:

```
list1 = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {5, -0.5}, {7, -0.4}};
list2 = {{2, -0.1}, {3, -2}, {5, -2.5}, {7, -3.4}};

operation = {#1[[1]], #1[[2]] - #2[[2]]} &;
MapThread[operation, {list1, list2}] 

(*{{2, -0.5}, {3, 1.1}, {5, 2.}, {7, 3.}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {5, -0.5}, {7, -0.4}};

b = {{2, -0.1}, {3, -2}, {5, -2.5}, {7, -3.4}};
```

Using `SequenceCases` with `Riffle`

```
SequenceCases[Riffle[a, b], {{x_, a_}, {x_, b_}} :> {x, a - b}]
```

> {{2, -0.5}, {3, 1.1}, {5, 2.}, {7, 3.}}

Using `GroupBy`

```
c = GroupBy[Join[a, b], First -> Last, Apply @ Subtract]
```

> <|2 -> -0.5, 3 -> 1.1, 5 -> 2., 7 -> 3.|>

Using `Merge` and `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
c = Merge[Apply @ Subtract] @ MapApply[Rule] @ Join[a, b]
```

> <|2 -> -0.5, 3 -> 1.1, 5 -> 2., 7 -> 3.|>

Convert to `List`

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ c
```

> {{2, -0.5}, {3, 1.1}, {5, 2.}, {7, 3.}}

Comment: `(Merge[{Rule @@@ l1, Rule @@@ l2}, Apply[Subtract]] // Normal) /. 
 Rule -> List`

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {5, -0.5}, {7, -0.4}};

l2 = {{2, -0.1}, {3, -2}, {5, -2.5}, {7, -3.4}};
```

---

Using `Thread` twice:

```
{#1[[1]], #2[[1]] - #2[[2]]} & @@@ Thread /@ Thread[{l1, l2}]
```

> `{{2, -0.5}, {3, 1.1}, {5, 2.}, {7, 3.}}`

Also:

```
Thread[{First@#1, First@#2 - Last@#2}] & @@ Thread[Thread /@ {l1, l2}]
```

> `{{2, -0.5}, {3, 1.1}, {5, 2.}, {7, 3.}}`